# PaLM API json not workings

Tags: lua, roblox, palm-api

ok... i solve my problem. the problem is on my self. i forgot to add the

```
return response
```

which is stupid on my side lol

here's the fixed code

```lua
--google palm--
--roblox lua

local Players = game:GetService("Players");
local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService");
local LocalPlayer = Players.LocalPlayer;
local RequestFunctiom = request;
local function MakeRequest(Prompt)
    local success, response = pcall(function()
        return RequestFunctiom({
           Url = "https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta2/models/text-bison-001:generateText?key=KEY_HERE",
            Method = "POST",
            Headers = {
                ["Content-Type"] = "application/json",
            },
            Body = HttpService:JSONEncode({
            prompt = {
              text = Prompt
            },
            temperature = 0.7,
            candidateCount = 1,
            topP = 0.95,
            topK = 5,
            maxOutputTokens = 100,
            stopSequences = {"Human:", "Ai:"},
            })
        })
    end)
    print(response)
    return response
end
print("MakeRequest sending")
print("test1")
local HttpRequest = MakeRequest("Human: Hello how are you today \n\nAI:");
--wait(3) -- if this added the local Response will errored the error is "attempt to index nil with the Body"
local Response =  ". " .. string.sub(HttpService:JSONDecode(HttpRequest["Body"]).candidates[1].output, 2);
print(Response)
```

Comment: try seting candidate_count  to 1

Comment: Where does `request` come from and why isn't it `HttpService:RequestAsync` ? How do you authenticate yourself? Did you debug, e.g., printed the raw answer of the request?

Comment: i fixed lol i stared the code for 10 minutes and realize i accidentally delete the return response i feel pain right now

Comment: Ouf, didn't see that either ^^ But in any case, please never modify the question like this, as it is then no longer a question. If you feel like the question does not help anyone else you can delete it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language that is but the proper JSon body for the request should be something like this

You defiantly have prompt and stop_sequences  wrong.

```
{
  "prompt": "Write a poem about an adventure in an underwater castle\n\n",
  "model_name": "models/text-bison-001",
  "temperature": 0.7,
  "candidate_count": 1,
  "top_k": 40,
  "top_p": 0.95,
  "max_output_tokens": 1024,
  "stop_sequences": []
}
```

## candidate_count

you have candidate_count  set to three which means that `HttpService:JSONDecode(response.Body).candidates` is an array.

It may be failing on that

Comment: its roblox lua lol

Comment: still can't figure it out still not working

Comment: i think local Response have an problem because it yield idk why

Comment: or maybe the url

Comment: the document is kinda confusing ngl

Comment: local Response = " " .. string.gsub(HttpService:JSONDecode(response.Body).candidates[1].output, "\n", " ")

Comment: still not working

Comment: i change the v1beta3 into v1beta2 nothing change except for an error

Comment: candidateCount set to 1

Answer (score 0):

fixed version

answered my own question. i feel dumb

```lua
--google palm--
--roblox lua

local Players = game:GetService("Players");
local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService");
local LocalPlayer = Players.LocalPlayer;
local RequestFunctiom = request;
local function MakeRequest(Prompt)
    local success, response = pcall(function()
        return RequestFunctiom({
           Url = "https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta2/models/text-bison-001:generateText?key=KEY_HERE",
            Method = "POST",
            Headers = {
                ["Content-Type"] = "application/json",
            },
            Body = HttpService:JSONEncode({
            prompt = {
              text = Prompt
            },
            temperature = 0.7,
            candidateCount = 1,
            topP = 0.95,
            topK = 5,
            maxOutputTokens = 100,
            stopSequences = {"Human:", "Ai:"},
            })
        })
    end)
    print(response)
    return response
end
print("MakeRequest sending")
print("test1")
local HttpRequest = MakeRequest("Human: Hello how are you today \n\nAI:");
--wait(3) -- if this added the local Response will errored the error is "attempt to index nil with the Body"
local Response =  ". " .. string.sub(HttpService:JSONDecode(HttpRequest["Body"]).candidates[1].output, 2);
print(Response)
```